# "Importing" another class in C#

Tags: c#, class, import, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 for a windows app, I have in my `MainForm` some code that is needing another piece of code in order to run, and I am trying to move this required code into another class alone and import it (to make the `MainForm` class more comfortable to understand)

I can't seem to be able to import that class when I move the code to it, here are some stuff that the coed includes:

```
static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
        IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    { .. }
```

and some

```
delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
```

so those were normally inside my

```
namespace myClass
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
```

but I want to put them in another class and kinda import them

Comment: U mean u want use [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms173149.aspx)?

Comment: Maybe but MainForm inherites Form already, I'll look for multiple Inheritance if it works

Comment: So Mainform : Form, myInterface didn't work also, hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to 'import' them just because the are in another class (same project). If you are using a different namespace then you *can* inlcude it, but you don't need to.

For example, you can put them in another class (probably better to be a static class, as they are static methods), and then call them from other code...

```
namespace SameNamespace
{
    static class NewClass
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
    }
}
```

then in your form code you just use the following wheneven you need it:

```
NewClass.GetWindowThreadProcessId(...);
```

---

If you want to put the class in a different namespace, for example:

```
namespace DifferentNamespace
{
    ...
```

then you either include it, like so:

```
using DifferentNamespace;
```

or you can just explicitly call it when you need the function:

```
 DifferentNamespace.NewClass.GetWindowThreadProcessId(...);
```

Comment: This solved most of it, thank's, but somehow some stuff like EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE are giving errors, something is still missing from the code

Comment: @user3795356: And what are those things? I don't see them in your question

Comment: Yeah, u should mark it as answer. These errors are from ur code